# Drop duplicated values with specific condition on another colunm pandas

Tags: pandas, duplicates, drop

I want to drop duplicate values on "Nit", but keeping when date "Date" is 31-12-2018

```
Nit       sales    date

12345      56    31-12-2018
12345      45    31-06-2018
23346      87    31-12-2018
76553      93    31-12-2018
44556      34    31-06-2018
44556      52    31-12-2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
(df.assign(valid_date=df['date']=='31-12-2018')
   .sort_values('valid_date', ascending=False)
   .drop_duplicates('Nit')
   .sort_index()
   .drop('valid_date', axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
     Nit  sales        date
0  12345     56  31-12-2018
2  23346     87  31-12-2018
3  76553     93  31-12-2018
5  44556     52  31-12-2018
```

**Note**: A simple

```
df[df['date']=='31-12-2018']
```

may do what you want.

Comment: woud the second way modify the entire df?

Comment: no, it slices a part of `df`. You can replace with `df = df[...]` or assign to a new dataframe `new_df = df[...].copy()`.

Comment: ins't there a way to set a personalized function to keep :  "df.drop_duplicates(subset ="Nit", keep = "personalize function", inplace = True)"  that personalized function would the values with the specific "data"